# How do I use DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey to give me an auto generated key?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to use DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey from the AWS SDK to give me a random key(of type String) that I can then use to do something. I can't find any examples online of doing this, and while it seems like it should be relatively straightforward I am really struggling to get this working. Can anyone link me to an example of this being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found easy answer.

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Screw using `DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey`, sounds like a headache.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Please note that UUID format would be something like this "3ea8e671-1e64-4cde-bd78-5980049a772b". If the id is going to be used by end users, please get confirmation from them whether the format is ok. In some use cases, this format is not acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

```
@DynamoDBTable( tableName = "Details")
public class Details
{
    @DynamoDBGeneratedUuid( DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE )
    private UUID id;
    ....
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public UUID getId()
    {
        return id; 
    }
    // also you need to add the setter otherwise you will get an exception
    public void setId(UUID id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
...
```

Comment: is this annotation @DynamoDBGeneratedUuid available...or it id self-made? can you please tell whole process you are doing here?