# DynamoDB transactional insert with multiple conditions (PK/SK attribute_not_exists and SK attribute_exists)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with PK (String) and SK (Integer) - e.g.

```
PK_id                   SK_version      Data
-------------------------------------------------------
c3d4cfc8-8985-4e5...    1               First version
c3d4cfc8-8985-4e5...    2               Second version
```

I can do a conditional insert to ensure we don't overwrite the PK/SK pair using ConditionalExpression (in the GoLang SDK):

```
putWriteItem := dynamodb.Put{
    TableName:                           "example_table",
    Item:                                itemMap,
    ConditionExpression:                 aws.String("attribute_not_exists(PK_id) AND attribute_not_exists(SK_version)"),
}
```

However I would also like to ensure that the SK_version is always consecutive but don't know how to write the expression.  In pseudo-code this is:

```
putWriteItem := dynamodb.Put{
    TableName:                           "example_table",
    Item:                                itemMap,
    ConditionExpression:                 aws.String("attribute_not_exists(PK_id) AND attribute_not_exists(SK_version) **AND attribute_exists(SK_version = :SK_prev_version)**"),
}
```

Can someone advise how I can write this?

in SQL I'd do something like:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (PK_id, SK_version, Data)
SELECT {pk}, {sk}, {data}
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT  1 
                    FROM    example_table
                    WHERE   PK_id = {pk}
                       AND  SK_version = {sk}
                 )
   AND EXISTS    (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    example_table
                    WHERE   PK_id = {pk}
                       AND  SK_version = {sk} - 1
                 )
```

Thanks

Comment: With the given condition, I don't understand how you insert the very first version? At first, there is no version existing.

Comment: Before the write, do you make GetItem/BatchGet in order to resolve SK_version for the write?

Comment: Would need a slightly different put for version 1 - basically that would be an ‘or’. From the accepted answer below you can see we can include this condition  (or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conditional check is applied to a single item. It cannot be spanned across multiple items. In other words, you simply need multiple conditional checks. DynamoDb has [transactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) API which performs multiple conditional checks, along with writes/deletes. The code below is in nodejs.

```
  const previousVersionCheck = {
    TableName: 'example_table',
    Key: {
      PK_id: 'prev_pk_id',
      SK_version: 'prev_sk_version'
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(PK_id)'
  }

  const newVersionPut = {
    TableName: 'example_table',
    Item: {
      // your item data
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(PK_id)'
  }

  await documentClient.transactWrite({
    TransactItems: [
      { ConditionCheck: previousVersionCheck },
      { Put: newVersionPut }
    ]
  }).promise()
```

The transaction has 2 operations: one is a validation against the previous version, and the other is an conditional write. Any of their conditional checks fails, the transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting your head on some of the differences between a SQL and a no-SQL database.  DynamoDB is, of course, a no-SQL database.  It does not, out of the box, support optimistic locking.  I see two straight forward options:

1. Use a software layer to give you locking on your DynamoDB table.  This may or may not be feasible depending on how often updates are made to your table.  How fast 'versions' are generated and the maximum time your application can be gated on the lock will likely tell you if this can work foryou.  I am not familiar with Go, but  the Java API [supports this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html).  Again, this isn't a built-in feature of DynamoDB.  If there is no such Go API equivalent, you could use the technique described in the link to 'lock' the table for updates.  Generally speaking, locking a no-SQL DB isn't a typical pattern as it isn't exactly what it was created to do (part of which is achieving large scale on unstructured documents to allow fast access to many consumers at once)
2. Stop using an incrementor to guarantee uniqueness.  Typically, incrementors are frowned upon in DynamoDB, in part due to the lack of intrinsic support for it and in part because of how DynamoDB shards you don't want a lot of similarity between records.  Using a UUID will solve the uniqueness problem, but if you are porting an existing application that means more changes to the elements that create that ID and updates to reading the ID (perhaps to include a creation-time field so you can tell which is the newest, or the prepending or appending of an epoch time to the UUID to do the same).  [Here is a pertinent link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816312/14114029) to a SO question explaining on why to use UUIDs instead of incrementing integers.

Comment: It’s a transactional write item item so optimistic locking is ok - the lock time is simply to add a single item. Versions are created maybe every second (sometimes faster) but they don’t normally go higher than 10 or so - the table is being used as an event sourcing store (which is essentially unstructured data).  Version increment is done in the code (not in Dynamo). The PK is a uuid to allow proper partitioning. Version is used to determine created order, a time stamp is also included for reference.

Comment: Seems like you are mostly doing it the same way I would, but I would ditch the incrementor and just use the timestamp as the SK now that I know you already have it in your message.  I would prefer to not have to hassle with the lock at all to keep my options open later (especially for more scalability if you need it), but you know the problem better than I.  Good luck.

Comment: The is o to prevent an (admitted rare) situation where two events are permitted by the code (I’m imagining a ORDER-DISPATCHED event is processed at exactly the same time as a ORDER-CANCEL-REQUESTED). We synchronise (using Kafka to partition orders on one consumer), so I could only imagine this happening if there is a partition rebalance that alters this, and retries are included so the loser gets to go again. But the question isn’t specifically about the lock, it’s about ensuring the version is one more than the previous.

Comment: … I.e. the retry would re-request the event stream and establish the next version correctly, but it’s safer to do a condition to check this when the write happens, I just don’t know how to write:    and (exists (streamId) and (version - 1))      In *addition* to (not exists (streamID) and (version)) which is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hung Tran's answer, here is a Go example:

```
checkItem := dynamodb.TransactWriteItem{
    ConditionCheck: &dynamodb.ConditionCheck{
        TableName:           "example_table",
        ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_exists(pk_id) AND attribute_exists(version)"),
        Key:                 map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{"pk_id": {S: id}, "version": {N: prevVer}},
    },
}
putItem := dynamodb.TransactWriteItem{
    Put: &dynamodb.Put{
        TableName:           "example_table",
        ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exists(pk_id) AND attribute_not_exists(version)"),
        Item:                data,
    },
}
writeItems := []*dynamodb.TransactWriteItem{&checkItem, &putItem}

_, _ = db.TransactWriteItems(&dynamodb.TransactWriteItemsInput{TransactItems: writeItems})
```